# preg_match - find forms that contain word A and not B

Tags: php, preg-match

I'm using PHP preg_match to find and parse specific forms on page. Until now my code worked well but I found that some unneeded forms now contain the word that I actually need, so these unneeded forms are parsed too. Put simply, I need to parse all forms that contain word "findme" and NOT contain word "ignoreme" in URL.

Here's my preg_match:

```
<form action=("|\'?)([0-9a-zA-Z:\/\._~\-\?=]+)findme(.*?)\/form>
```

Unfortunately, if form URL is like /some_url/ignoreme/findme/whatever, the code still parses it, which I don't want. How should I modify the code?

Comment: are the two words inside attributes or text? or always in the action attribute? (for information regex is not the way to go, using DOMXPath is easier)

Comment: I need to parse only forms that contain this word in "action" attribute

Answer (score 0):

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($yourHTML);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$formNodeList = $xpath->query('//form[contains(@action, "findme") and not(contains(@action, "ignoreme"))]');

foreach($formNodeList as $formNode) {
    // do what you want with the DOMNode (see php manual)
}
```

Comment: The code gives this error:

Warning: DOMXPath::query(): Invalid predicate
Warning: DOMXPath::query(): Invalid expression

The error is somewhere in this line - $formNodeList =...